# Unable to create a second level in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, animation

I made a game in flash, and the first level of the game works, but after you complete the level, I am unsure of the coding to test and see if all of the enemies, since they are movie clips, have been unloaded from the flash, so it will move on to the second level. I know there is a way to do it, I just don't know exactly how, to do it, nor do i know where to look to get help with it.

here's the coding i've done so far.

this is the coding I've put one of the enemy characters, who is a movie clip, they all have different values to make things interesting.

```
onClipEvent (enterFrame){
    if(_root.spaceship._y>_y) {_y +=5;}

    if(_root.spaceship._y<_y) {_y -=5;}

    if(_root.spaceship._x>_x) {_x +=5;}

    if(_root.spaceship._x<_x) {_x -=5;}
}
```

This is the coding I've put on my player, which happens to be a spaceship.

```
//Initialize Variable
onClipEvent(load) {
       var shipSpeed:Number = 20;
       var rotationSpeed:Number = 20;
       var missileNum:Number = 0;
       var missile:Array = new Array();
       var missleSpeed:Number = 30;
}



onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
       if(Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)) {
               _rotation -= rotationSpeed;
       }

       if(Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)) {
               _rotation += rotationSpeed;
       }

       var radian:Number = (-1 * _rotation + 90) * Math.PI/180;

       if(Key.isDown(Key.UP)) {
               _x += shipSpeed * Math.cos(radian);
               _y -= shipSpeed * Math.sin(radian);
       }

       if(Key.isDown(Key.DOWN)) {
               _x -= shipSpeed * Math.cos(radian);
               _y += shipSpeed * Math.sin(radian);
       }

    //hit test
    if(this.hitTest(_root.enemy1))
        {
            //trace("spaceship")
            _root.spaceship.play(2);
        }


//Shoot missile in direction the ship is facing
       if(Key.isDown(Key.SPACE)) {
               missile[missileNum] =
               _root.attachMovie("missile","missile"+missileNum,_root.getNextHighestDepth(),{_x:_x,_y:_y,_rotation:_rotation});
               missile[missileNum].ySpeed = Math.sin(radian)*missleSpeed;
               missile[missileNum].xSpeed = Math.cos(radian)*missleSpeed;
               missile[missileNum].onEnterFrame = function() {
                       if(this.hitTest(_root.enemy)) {
                               _root.enemy.play (13);


               if(this.hitTest(_root.enemy1)) {
                       this.play()
                       _root.enemy1.play(13);

               }

               if(this.hitTest(_root.enemy2)) {
                       this.play()
                       _root.enemy2.play(13);

               }

               if(this.hitTest(_root.enemy3)) {
                       this.play()
                       _root.enemy3.play(13);

               }

               if(this.hitTest(_root.enemy4)) {
                       this.play()
                       _root.enemy4.play(13);

               }

               if(this.hitTest(_root.enemy5)) {
                       this.play()
                       _root.enemy5.play(13);

               }


// this.attachMovie("enemy", "enemy", 3 );
                       }
                       this._y -= this.ySpeed;
                       this._x += this.xSpeed;
                       trace("missile: " + missileNum);
                       if(0 > this._x || this._x > 1000000000 || 0 > this._y || this._y > 1000000000)
                               this.removeMovieClip();
               }
               missileNum++;
       }

}
```

if you can't directly help me, could you point me in the right direction or send me a link to a webpage that would help me understand actionscript a little better.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a variable to keep track of how many enemies are left. Every time you add an enemy to the scene, increment the variable. Every time an enemy is destroyed, decrement the variable. Then in the ship's enterFrame function just check that variable.

I concur about moving to AS3, much better for structuring the code. It took me a minute when looking at your code to realize it's AS2. I'm remembering that all the different functions are accessed by clicking different objects on the stage and it makes me shudder.

Comment: When i create the variable, what would be the proper syntax to create it? I can't seem to get the condition to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array which contains the destroyed enemies

```
var deadEnemies:Array = [];

if(this.hitTest(_root.enemy5)) {
    this.play()
    _root.enemy5.play(13);
    if (deadEnemies.indexOf(_root.enemy5) == -1)
    {
        deadEnemies.push(_root.enemy5);
    }
 }
```

and then test it

```
if (deadEnemies.length == 5)
{
    trace("level2");
}
```

Furthermore, I think this won't help, but I have to say it:

- Forget about AS2
- Do everything you can to keep things dynamic, a dynamic number of enemies for instance.
- Don't listen for keypress in an enterframe, there is a specialized event for that, use it ;)
- Don't write functions inside other functions, you can name them and separate everything.
- Your math seems good and you write things neatly, if you want to go one step beyond, take a look at Object Oriented Programming.

Cheers